# No output when using React query

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I wrote the following code using React Query

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import Axios from "axios";

export const Reactqueryex = () => {
const { data, isLoading, isError, refetch } = useQuery(  {
    queryKey: "cat",
    queryFn: () => {
      Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data);
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Generate Random Cat Fact using React query</p>
      <button onClick={refetch}>Update Fact</button>
      <p>The fact is: {data?.fact}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But there is no output shown.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiUpZ.png)

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

The `queryFn` [must return a promise](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/query-functions), you are missing a `return` to return the axios promise:

```
queryFn: () => {
      return Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data);
},
```